configparser unable to read [DEFAULT] as key value?
Why can't I use configparser to read a ini file with a [DEFAULT] key?
Something simple as this
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")
print(config.sections())
#output []

#config.ini
[DEFAULT]
key1 = 2
key2 = 4

It simply print out [], with no value. Why is that?
note: Use anything but [DEFAULT] works, even lower case [default] works too. (on window machine, don't know if that has anything to do with it)
Trying to understand why...Is there any work around? In case that I can't modify the ini file.

Work-around: config = configparser.ConfigParser(default_section=''). That is, just change the name of the default section to some unused value. This of course assumes the ini file isn't making use of the default section for interpolating values. And also note that, even without this work-around, you can still access the values like this: config['DEFAULT']['key1'].

"DEFAULT" is a special section the provides default values to other sections. The fact that it doesn't appear in sections is well documented:

sections()
Return a list of the sections available; the default section is not included in the list.

